# setTimeout only runs once in loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, for-loop, settimeout

My goal is to perform the javascript function every X amount of seconds. I've read that setInterval should be used but I don't believe so in my case. I also don't want the variables to have to be resent just incase the user decides to change things before everything was officially sent

For example, I put 60 in time and 5 in amount but it waited 60 seconds and then just sent 5 instead, 1 text every 60 seconds until it had sent 5 texts

my javascript

```
    $('input[name="sendtxt"]').click(function(e) {
        sendText(e);
    });

function sendText(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var phonenum = $('input[name="phonenum"]').val();
    var provider = $('select[name="provider"]').val();
    var message = $('textarea[name="message"]').val();
    var otherprov = $('input[name="otherprov"]').val();
    var amount = $('input[name="amount"]').val();
    var time = $('input[name="time"]').val() * 1000;
    var sendmsg;
    for (sendmsg = 1; sendmsg <= amount; sendmsg++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    provider: provider,
                    message: message,
                    phonenum: phonenum,
                    amount: amount,
                    otherprov: otherprov,
                    time: time
                },
                url: 'send.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log('Success. Sent ' + sendmsg + " texts.");
                },
                error: function(xhr, err) {
                    console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                    console.log("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        }, time);
    }
```

and my PHP

```
<?php


$to = $_POST["phonenum"];
$provider = $_POST["provider"];

$otherprov = $_POST["otherprov"];
$fixedotherprov = str_replace("otherprovider", "", $otherprov);


$completenum = $to . $provider . $fixedotherprov;
$completenum = str_replace('otherprovider', '', $completenum);
$subject = 'Hello';
$message = $_POST["message"];
$headers = 'From: Daniel';
$amount = $_POST["amount"];

//for ($x = 0; $x < $amount; $x++) {
    mail($completenum, $subject, $message, $headers);
//}

?>
```

Comment: Note: `setTimeout` will be run in single thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout`is an asynchronous function. The timeout events are defined in your loop from `sendmsg = 1` to `sendmsg <= amount`. After executing the for loop, rest of the code below the for loop is being executed until the timeout event fires. When the timeout events are fired, the value of `sendmsg` is equal to `amount+1` as the loop is already finished execution. Therefore all the timeout events gets value of `sendmsg`as `amout+1` leading the unexpected behaviour..

In the code below, a temporary scope is defined at each iteration which gives different `sendmsg` value to each `timeout` event.

You also have to schedule different times as the timeout time value in each iteration in order to execute them in different timeouts.

Modify your code like this..

```
function sendText(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var phonenum = $('input[name="phonenum"]').val();
    var provider = $('select[name="provider"]').val();
    var message = $('textarea[name="message"]').val();
    var otherprov = $('input[name="otherprov"]').val();
    var amount = $('input[name="amount"]').val();
    var time = $('input[name="time"]').val();
    var sendmsg;
    for (sendmsg = 1; sendmsg <= amount; sendmsg++) {
            (function(sendmsg){
               setTimeout(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        provider: provider,
                        message: message,
                        phonenum: phonenum,
                        amount: amount,
                        otherprov: otherprov,
                        time: time * 1000 * sendmsg
                    },
                    url: 'send.php',
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log('Success. Sent ' + sendmsg + " texts.");
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, err) {
                        console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                        console.log("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }, time * 1000 * sendmsg);
           })(sendmsg);
        }
}
```

Comment: I put your code in and I believe that at the moment it waits until time but then after that it send amount all at once. I'm not sure if i was clear but the goal was for it to send amount of texts, 1 text at a time every time seconds

Comment: Then you have to change the time values used in the timeout function at each iteration. I changed the code. Check if it works now..

Answer (score 0):

this is a matter of scope.

read more about Javascript closure (scoped) functions: http://brackets.clementng.me/post/24150213014/example-of-a-javascript-closure-settimeout-inside

change your code to:

```
for (sendmsg = 1; sendmsg <= amount; sendmsg++) {
    (function(){
        setTimeout(function(_provider, _message, _phonenum, _amount, _otherprov, _time, _sendmsg) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    provider: _provider,
                    message: _message,
                    phonenum: _phonenum,
                    amount: _amount,
                    otherprov: _otherprov,
                    time: _time
                },
                url: 'send.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log('Success. Sent ' + _sendmsg + " texts.");
                },
                error: function(xhr, err) {
                    console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                    console.log("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        }, time);
    })(provider, message, phonenum, amount, otherprov, time, sendmsg);
}
```

hope that helps.

Comment: 1. When you say to change my code, you mean only the for loop, not the whole thing right? 2. And I'm not too sure why you put _ in front of things?

Comment: just change your whole `for` code with the code i provided, which includes a scoped function with local inner vars (_provider, _message, etc.). - besides that you don't need to change anything.

Comment: I put your code in and I believe that at the moment it waits until `time` but then after that it send `amount` all at once. I'm not sure if i was clear but the goal was for it to send `amount` of texts, 1 text at a time every `time` seconds

Comment: For example, I put 60 in time and 5 in amount but it waited 60 seconds and then just sent 5 instead, 1 text every 60 seconds until it had sent 5 texts